# Dropbox Url Masking

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropbox

Note: I posted this in dropboxforum at: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/Masking-Dropbox-URL/m-p/217458#M11358

We have a Dropbox bussiness account.

And we want to move several files from our web site server into dropbox and use dropbox as a storage solution.

When a user wants to downoad one of these files we would like to keep the URL pointing to our domain and download the file dirctly from dropbox.

Our site is based in ASP.Net ( C# )

I found several solution of how to do this using the old Public folder, but I haven't been able to find an updated solution.

I woudn't mind to have this files publicly shared and even keeping a table in the database with each shared link. 
But I rather have the URL:
 
https://www.OurDomain.com/File?id=1 
instead of:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fxwygu566u3u2l6/doc.pdf?dl=0

EDIT:
[Here's an article](https://www.labnol.org/software/dropbox-with-custom-domain/18349/) explaining exactly what I want to do, but its based on the OLD public folder of Dropbox, when you could predict the URL in dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DownloadAsync](http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_DownloadAsync_1.htm) method, which is part of Dropbox API. Based on an example from the [Dropbox.NET tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/dotnet#tutorial), you can do this:

```
async Task Download(DropboxClient dbx, string folder, string file)
{
    using (var response = await dbx.Files.DownloadAsync(folder + "/" + file))
    {
        return response.GetContentAsByteArrayAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Our files are big so, this solutuon was timing out. We implemented a similar solution downloading chunks [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43208069/dropbox-net-downloading-large-files-using-getcontentasstreamasync) which works, but we want to download directly from Dropbox and removing the extra work from our website server.

Comment: If the files are large, implement a stand-alone mechanism to request, download in background, cache (to a temp directory) and serve files. Clear the temp directory when `HttpApplication.Application_Start` event occurs. Create an `internal static instance` of this Downloader class inside the `Global` class. Display a "Fetching file / please wait" message to user while file is downloading.

Comment: To avoid downloading the file server-side, you may create a [shared link](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-create_shared_link_with_settings) and redirect the user using [HttpResponse.Redirect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt.aspx) method. This will expose the Dropbox URL to your user.

Comment: I guess I didn't make myself clear, I have the shared link and I would like to redirect the user but I want to mask the URL...

Comment: I believe that is not possible. Unless you would be the downloading and re-transmitting in the background - as you already tried.